# Why has no one requested the tape of the Trump/Ukraine call?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, ukraine, trump-impeachment

Given that the transcript released [is not word for word](https://apnews.com/8f96294c8bc44ad485d74a7a0b0a0e00) and that it [contains a disclaimer explaining it's not a 'verbatim transcript'](https://theweek.com/speedreads/867567/ukraine-transcript-contains-disclaimer-explaining-not-verbatim-transcript), why has no one, whether Democrats seeking to impeach, or Republicans seeking to defend, requested the original tape, in order that it can be heard/transcribed verbatim?

---

[Update] some have pointed out that presidential 'phone calls are not recorded on audio tape, so I will rephrase the question to "why has no one demanded whatever it was that was [moved to a secret server](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/white-house-lawyer-moved-transcript-of-trump-call-to-classified-server-after-ukraine-adviser-raised-alarms/2019/10/30/ba0fbdb6-fb4e-11e9-8190-6be4deb56e01_story.html)"?

I.e this:

> The White House has admitted moving details of a telephone call between Donald Trump and his Ukrainian counterpart to a classified server, according to CNN.
>
> The admission appears to back up one of the claims made by a whistleblower about efforts to conceal evidence of the controversial call, which has led to an impeachment investigation against the president.

[source](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/trump-ukraine-call-white-house-secret-server-impeachment-a9123536.html)

Why is no one asking to see/hear whatever was moved to that secret server?

Comment: You are assuming that "a tape" exists of audio of the two presidents. I'm not at all certain that your assumption is correct. Secondly, "tape" is usually associated with an analog recording of audio, today's technology (with the possible exception of the music industry) relies on digital recordings that are preserved in digital records or files.

Comment: @BobE related: [*Are the US President's phone calls recorded?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/15253/18862)

Comment: Yes, as well  https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/47230/15671

Comment: @BobE "tape" is used colloquially to refer to any unedited audio or video recording, not just ones on physical tapes.

Comment: @JustinLardinois - my comment was not intended to be critical, but to be more technically correct. In the colloquial sense, however, "tape" can be **either** ediited or unedited

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Republicans, seeking to defend the July 25 telephone conversation have been frustrated because the White House that has actively blocked or refused to cooperate in their own defense. If the verbatim transcription would provide the administration with an effective defense, the refusal, or neglect to provide exculpatory evidence gives the appearance that the verbatim transcript might be more damaging versus helpful in defense.

Democrats, on the other hand, have asked the White House for documents relative to the 25 July telephone call [Committee request for documents Sept 9 and 24](https://intelligence.house.gov/uploadedfiles/2019-09-24.eec_engel_schiff_to_cipollone-wh_re_potus_ukraine.pdf) and have been rebuffed by White House Counsel [Cippolone letter to Schiff et al](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/trump-impeachment-inquiry/white-house-refuses-turn-over-documents-democrats-impeachment-inquiry-n1063771) and [PDF](https://www.scribd.com/document/429357573/White-House-Letter-to-Speaker-Pelosi-Et-Al-10-08-2019#download&from_embed).  The transcript is specifically called out in the Sept 24th letter:

> "documents requested by the Committees - particularily the transcript pf the President's July 25, 2019, phone call with newly-elected Ukrainian President"

In addition, the Inspector General for the intelligence committee has notified the Director of National Intelligence:

> For your information, the ICIG has sent, concurrently with this transmittal, a notice of document access request and a document hold notice to the White House counsel to request access to and the preservation of any and all records related to the President's telephone call with the Ukranian President on July 25, 2019 ...

By anyone's definition the words "any and all" would encompass the raw, unedited transcript.

Comment: Pure opinion.  I'll note that it's undisputed that Rep Schiff has not approved quite a few Republican-requested witnesses, so while your opinion that "the White House has actively blocked or refused to cooperate in their own defense" may or may not be true, it's indisputable that Rep Schiff has blocked White House attempts at defense.

Comment: @JustMe The list of witnesses requested are a matter of public record, and the only two that I can find that were denied were the original whistleblower and Hunter Biden. Considering we have much better witnesses now than the whistleblower and that Hunter Biden has absolutely nothing useful to say in whether or not Donald J Trump committed a crime, I fail to see how the Democrats are impeding his defense.

Comment: @JustMe, see my added sources for "actively blocked or refused..."   Regardless, the question asked is: Why has no one requested the tape? In that context, if "the tape" would provide exculpatory evidence, the WH ought to present it. As of this date I've not heard any Republican asking to enter it into evidence.

Comment: @Just Me: While I am not a lawyer, my understanding of whistleblower protection laws is that it would be illegal for the whistleblower to be called and identified as being the whistleblower.

Comment: @jamesqf - I believe that the whistleblower could be called _without_ them being identified as such, or they can be called as an anonymous whistleblower and [have their identity hidden](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/47491/2130) while they testify.  It'd only be calling them to testify by both name and whistleblower status that may be illegal.

Comment: @Bobson: FTM, the whistleblower might even be among the list of witnesses to be called.  (Or might even be one of those refusing to respond to the Congressional subpoena.)  As long as s/he isn't actually identified as the whistleblower, there shouldn't be a problem.  But if there are better witnesses, or even hard evidence like call transcripts, what would be the point?

Comment: @jamesqf If a transcript, written by a Trump staffer, was released, then it would be immediately discarded as fake. We are deep in he said she said territory now. Let's be honest, even if there was a recording it would be under suspicion as possibly doctored.

Comment: @jgn - there's the problem: The "transcript" released by the WH **was written** by staffers. At minimum it was edited by staffers, so using your logic, this transcript (the one released by the WH) ought to be considered "fake". (BTW, I'm not rejecting your logic - I'm just suggesting, the logic you suggest also applies to the TELCON that was released.

Comment: @jamesqf - The [law](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/STATUTE-103/pdf/STATUTE-103-Pg16.pdf) specifically states that the whistleblower's identity "may not be disclosed by the [Office of the] Special Counsel" (the entity whistleblower reports are filed with).  It doesn't appear to say anything about anyone *else* disclosing it.

Comment: Notice how this Q&A has been derailed into discussion of whistleblower's identity. That has nothing to do with the title question. Classic deflection.

Comment: @jgn: But we do have a partial transcript, presumably written by a Trump staffer and approved by Trump.  Yet AFAIK nobody claimed that was fake.

Comment: Lt. Col. Vindman said that certain words were deliberately left out of the transcript summary even after he tried to get them added back in. His attempts were unsuccessful. This suggests (but does not prove) that others in the White House chose to exclude key words to avoid incriminating the president.

Comment: @jamesqf OK, I'll play in the deflection game with jgn... Trump released "the transcript" of his 21 April call to Pres Z on Thursday. Nowhere on that call is there any mention of corruption by either party. And yet, the readout (briefing to the press)  just after that call that the two discussed corruption. One has to conclude that either the readout was incorrect or the "transcript" is incorrect.

Comment: there is a peculiarity about the April 21 "transcript": The caution at the bottom of the first page specifically notes that an "interpreter facilitated this conversation" .  There is no such cautionary note on the July 25 "transcript", the implication is that an interpreter was **not** used on the July call. See previous SE Q&As that rely on the premise that an interpreter was used on the July call to explain the length of time that call took.

Comment: @BobE that is what happened, transcript was released, yet there are still calls for the transcript because it was assumed doctored.

Comment: @jgn vindmann has testified the 25 July TELCON (aka the transcript) was doctored- no assumption needed!

Comment: @BobE Of course, the transcript was made by Trump and released by Trump. As soon as it, the only piece of evidence, existed it was under suspicion. What's more, it was never claimed to be verbatim.

Comment: @jgn, Trump claimed repeatedly it was verbatim, word for word, comma for comma

Comment: @BobE Is that so? The press release said it wasn't. I don't keep up with Trump's twitter.

Comment: Trump said at rallies, said on the South Lawn several times, and at Q&A's after meeting with foreign leaders. Reported by factcheck, Politico, even saw it on FNC

Answer (score 41):

[Richard Nixon was the last president](https://millercenter.org/the-presidency/secret-white-house-tapes/about) to record his phone calls, and they were used against him in his impeachment. Between 1974 and 2017, presidents have not recorded their phone calls, instead relying on written transcripts by those intelligence officials listening in on the call. In 2017, [President Trump further restricted](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/09/24/us/politics/trump-calls-world-leaders.html) who was allowed to listen in on his phone calls and who was allowed to write notes, restricting it to only those people he had personally hired.

> Rough transcripts of the calls — there are no recordings from which
>   they are based, and they can vary in their level of detail — were, at
>   the beginning of the administration, widely shared documents that
>   could be viewed by the White House chief of staff, officials at the
>   National Security Council and people working in the region at the
>   State Department or the Defense Department. That changed after the
>   full transcripts of Mr. Trump’s conversations with the president of
>   Mexico and the prime minister of Australia were leaked in 2017. In his
>   call with Mexico’s leader, Mr. Trump stated that he was not actually
>   concerned with whether Mexico would pay for the wall he wanted to
>   build on the southwestern border, his signature campaign promise, but
>   grew testy about the way it might look if Mexico didn’t. “If you are
>   going to say that Mexico is not going to pay for the wall, then I do
>   not want to meet with you guys anymore because I cannot live with
>   that,” Mr. Trump said, according to the transcript. The Trump
>   administration took what one official called “extreme steps” to
>   restrict who can listen in on the president’s phone calls. The leaks
>   fed Mr. Trump’s fear that a “deep state” embedded in the government
>   was seeking to undermine him from within. A second former official
>   said those leaks were viewed internally as “really shocking” and under
>   the orders of Michael T. Flynn, Mr. Trump’s first national security
>   adviser, the decision was made to tightly limit the distribution of
>   the transcripts.

So unless the Ukrainians recorded the call (which they have not as yet admitted to doing), there is no audio recording, and all transcripts were made by Trump appointees.

Comment: It is a bit into the weeds, but my understanding is that, while you are quite correct about audio recordings of the president's voice on telephone calls, but the actual transcription process involves a transcriptionist (called a "voice writer" - look it up) who **repeats** verbatim (word for word) everything that is said on both sides of the conversation. The audio of the voice-writer is converted to digital text using speech recognition software that is displayed, in real time on networked computers. Generally both the audio of the voice-writer and the software output are preserved.

Comment: continuing... those records are covered under the Presidential Records Act. The software output is subsequently provided to the note-takers (generally and characteristically NSC personnel) who "edit" the verbatim transcript. This is the role that Lt Col Vindman participated, as an editor.

Comment: @BobE - Do you have a source for that?  The existence of a recording of a (nominally) word-for-word repetition of the call casts a very different light on what has and hasn't been released, and I haven't come across anyone else saying that such a recording exists.

Comment: "Richard Nixon was the last president to record his phone calls" - that we know of.

Comment: @Bobson, sure [ https://www.washingtonpost.com/national-security/2019/09/25/transcripts-presidential-calls-are-nearly-verbatim-not-exact-heres-how-it-works/ ], In that article Laurence Pfieffer, former Senior Director of the WH Situation Room, explains that a staffer (listening in real time) repeats what he is hearing (on the call) into voice recognition software (I think he really means 'speech recognition software') that produces the rough transcript. (my note: this process is used extensively in courtrooms/legal venues where a transcript is needed soon after the proceedings.

Comment: @Bobson  continuing: after checking with several commercial transcription companies (that provide services for Congressional hearings), they tell me that they will traditionally maintain the audio recording of the transcriptionist (person repeating  the words they hear on the call) as well as the digital output from the speech recognition software for a minimum of 6 months.  The point is that there is , at minimum, a digital record/file of the software's output. It is this file that Vindland complains he had to print (go analog) because he was unable to do on screen editing (think Word markup)

Comment: Perhaps they could ask Putin to give us [his recordings of the calls](https://www.cnn.com/2019/11/14/politics/bill-taylor-gordon-sondland-call-trump-security-concerns/index.html).

Comment: " President Trump further restricted who was allowed to listen in on his phone calls and who was allowed to write notes, restricting it to only those people he had personally hired." LOL, that makes his Ukraine call transcript all the more damning. :D